# Apache CXF 2.7.1 ResponseReader

Tags: web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, cxf

I'm working through a tutorial that uses Apache CXF 2.6.2 to create a RESTful web service. I installed version 2.7.1 (the latest at the time), because the tutorial indicated that any version 2.6.2 or later would work, and I figured why not use the latest. I am creating the client, and the tutorial directs me to use `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ResponseReader`. The problem is that Eclipse tells me "ResponseReader cannot be resolved to a type" and trying to import the class also gives an error. I searched the internet some, and it sounds like ResponseReader is no longer available in CXF 2.7.x. My question is, what is the alternative to ResponseReader in 2.7.x to represent the return value of a REST invocation as XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [this web page](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/27-migration-guide.html):

> JAX-RS: 3 classes have been removed from the org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client package: ResponseReader... The first class in the list is not needed with JAX-RS 2.0 Response class...

So, I guess that answers my question. There is no replacement per se, it's just not needed anymore.